# Not Showing A Letter When Using Java Font

Tags: java, fonts

I was fooling around in Java,when I decided to make a font class, and my own fonts. Everything prints all right, but when I type "Hello World" into the code, the program shows "Hello Xorld!". I tried switching the X and W, but then it shows "Hello Yorld", and so on. Any fixes?

Also, when I try to type in Hello Xorld, it spits out "Hello Yorld".

```
public class Font {
    private static String chars="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSRTUVWXYZ      0123456789.,:;'\"!?$%()-=+/      ";

    public static void render (String msg,Screen screen,int x,int y,int colour){
        msg= msg.toUpperCase();

        for (int i=0;i<msg.length();i++) {
            int charIndex= chars.indexOf(msg.charAt(i));
            if (charIndex>=0)screen.render(x+(i*8), y, charIndex+30*32, colour);
        }
    }
}
```

In a different class:

```
Font.render("Hello World 0157",screen,0,0,Colours.get(000,-1,-1,555));
```

Comment: Post your code here not on another site

Comment: It's a good idea to use Pastebin if you've a large amount of code, all of which is required to debug the problem. Your problem is very simple and involves a small amount of code, so it's better to include the code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your char[] array, you have this:

```
....ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSRTUVWXYZ....      
.                      ^
```

Note the extra R that comes after the S. Change this to:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Otherwise every letter after that S will be one out of position.

Comment: Wow... Thanks for responding so fast with a fix!